# How to plot grouped bars in the correct order

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, pandas-groupby, bar-chart

I am making a grouped bar chart of proficiency levels on a standardized test. Here is my code:

```
bush_prof_boy = bush.groupby(['BOY Prof'])['BOY Prof'].count()
bush_prof_pct_boy = bush_prof_boy/bush['BOY Prof'].count() * 100
bush_prof_eoy = bush.groupby(['EOY Prof'])['EOY Prof'].count()
bush_prof_pct_eoy = bush_prof_eoy/bush['EOY Prof'].count() * 100

labels = ['Remedial', 'Below Proficient', 'Proficient', 'Advanced']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, bush_prof_pct_boy, width, label='BOY', 
color='mediumorchid')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, bush_prof_pct_eoy, width, label='EOY', color='teal')

ax.set_ylabel('% of Students at Proficiency Level', fontsize=18)
ax.set_title('Bushwick Middle Change in Proficiency Levels', fontsize=25)
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels, fontsize=25)
ax.legend(fontsize=25)
plt.yticks(fontsize=15)


plt.figure(figsize=(5,15))

plt.show()
```

"BOY" stands for "Beginning of Year" and "EOY" "End of Year" so the bar graph is intended to show percent of students who fell into each proficiency level at the beginning and end of the year. The graph looks alright but when I drill into the numbers, I can see that the labels for EOY are incorrect. Here is my graph:

[image]

The percentages for BOY are graphed correctly, but the EOY ones are with the wrong labels. Here are the actual percentages, which I am certain are correct:

```
BOY %
Advanced            14.0
Below Proficient    38.0
Proficient          34.0
Remedial            14.0

EOY %
Advanced            39.0
Below Proficient    18.0
Proficient          32.0
Remedial            11.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Using data from [Kaggle: Brooklyn NY Schools](https://www.kaggle.com/gndoshi/sample-performance-of-2schools-brooklyn)
- Calculating the bar groups separately can be problematic. **It is better to make the calculations within one dataframe**, shape the dataframe, and then plot, because this will ensure the bars are plotted in the correct groups.
- Since no data is provided, this begins with wide form numeric data and then cleans and shapes the dataframe.

  - Numeric values are converted to categorical with [`.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)
  - Dataframe is converted to long form with [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), and then use [`.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to calculate percentage within the `'x of Year'`
  - Reshaped with [`.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), and plot with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)
- **Tested in `python 3.8`, `pandas 1.3.1`, and `matplotlib 3.4.2`**

### Imports, Load and Clean the DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np

# data 
data = {'BOY': [11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 11.0, 8.0, 11.0, 14.0, 12.0, 13.0, 11.0, 14.0, 10.0, 9.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 12.0, 12.0, 13.0, 12.0, 11.0, 9.0, 12.0, 16.0, 12.0, 12.0, 12.0, 15.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 8.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, 10.0, 8.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, 12.0, 13.0, 15.0, 13.0, 8.0, 8.0, 11.0, 10.0, 11.0, 13.0, 11.0, 13.0, 15.0, 10.0, 8.0, 10.0, 9.0, 8.0, 11.0, 13.0, 11.0, 8.0, 11.0, 15.0, 11.0, 12.0, 17.0, 12.0, 11.0, 18.0, 14.0, 15.0, 16.0, 7.0, 11.0, 15.0, 16.0, 13.0, 13.0, 13.0, 0.0, 11.0, 15.0, 14.0, 11.0, 13.0, 16.0, 14.0, 12.0, 8.0, 13.0, 13.0, 14.0, 7.0, 10.0, 16.0, 10.0, 13.0, 10.0, 14.0, 8.0, 16.0, 13.0, 12.0, 14.0, 12.0, 14.0, 16.0, 15.0, 13.0, 13.0, 10.0, 14.0, 8.0, 10.0, 10.0, 11.0, 12.0, 10.0, 12.0, 14.0, 17.0, 13.0, 14.0, 16.0, 15.0, 13.0, 16.0, 9.0, 16.0, 15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 15.0, 14.0, 12.0, 15.0, 11.0, 16.0, 14.0, 14.0, 15.0, 14.0, 14.0, 14.0, 16.0, 15.0, 12.0, 12.0, 14.0, 15.0, 13.0, 14.0, 13.0, 17.0, 14.0, 13.0, 14.0, 13.0, 13.0, 12.0, 10.0, 15.0, 14.0, 12.0, 12.0, 14.0, 12.0, 14.0, 13.0, 15.0, 13.0, 14.0, 14.0, 12.0, 11.0, 15.0, 14.0, 14.0, 10.0], 'EOY': [16.0, 16.0, 16.0, 14.0, 10.0, 14.0, 16.0, 14.0, 15.0, 15.0, 15.0, 11.0, 11.0, 15.0, 10.0, 14.0, 17.0, 14.0, 9.0, 15.0, 14.0, 16.0, 14.0, 13.0, 11.0, 13.0, 12.0, 14.0, 15.0, 13.0, 14.0, 15.0, 12.0, 19.0, 9.0, 13.0, 11.0, 14.0, 17.0, 17.0, 14.0, 13.0, 14.0, 10.0, 16.0, 15.0, 12.0, 11.0, 12.0, 14.0, 15.0, 10.0, 15.0, 14.0, 14.0, 15.0, 18.0, 15.0, 10.0, 10.0, 15.0, 15.0, 13.0, 15.0, 19.0, 13.0, 18.0, 20.0, 21.0, 17.0, 18.0, 17.0, 18.0, 17.0, 12.0, 16.0, 15.0, 18.0, 19.0, 17.0, 20.0, 11.0, 18.0, 19.0, 11.0, 12.0, 17.0, 20.0, 17.0, 15.0, 13.0, 18.0, 14.0, 17.0, 12.0, 12.0, 16.0, 12.0, 14.0, 15.0, 14.0, 10.0, 20.0, 13.0, 18.0, 20.0, 11.0, 20.0, 17.0, 20.0, 13.0, 17.0, 15.0, 18.0, 14.0, 13.0, 13.0, 18.0, 10.0, 13.0, 12.0, 18.0, 20.0, 20.0, 16.0, 18.0, 15.0, 20.0, 22.0, 18.0, 21.0, 18.0, 18.0, 18.0, 17.0, 16.0, 19.0, 16.0, 20.0, 19.0, 19.0, 20.0, 20.0, 14.0, 18.0, 20.0, 20.0, 18.0, 16.0, 21.0, 20.0, 18.0, 15.0, 14.0, 17.0, 19.0, 21.0, 14.0, 18.0, 15.0, 18.0, 21.0, 19.0, 17.0, 16.0, 16.0, 15.0, 20.0, 19.0, 16.0, 21.0, 17.0, 19.0, 15.0, 18.0, 20.0, 18.0, 20.0, 18.0, 16.0, 16.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# replace numbers with categorical labels; could also create new columns
labels = ['Remedial', 'Below Proficient', 'Proficient', 'Advanced']
bins = [1, 11, 13, 15, np.inf]
df['BOY'] = pd.cut(x=df.BOY, labels=labels, bins=bins, right=True)
df['EOY'] = pd.cut(x=df.EOY, labels=labels, bins=bins, right=True)

# melt the relevant columns into a long form
dfm = df.melt(var_name='Tested', value_name='Proficiency')

# set the categorical label order, which makes the xaxis labels print in the specific order
dfm['Proficiency'] = pd.Categorical(dfm['Proficiency'], labels, ordered=True)
```

### Groupby, Percent Calculation, and Shape for Plotting

```
# groupby and get the value counts
dfg = dfm.groupby('Tested')['Proficiency'].value_counts().reset_index(level=1, name='Size').rename({'level_1': 'Proficiency'}, axis=1)

# divide by the Tested value counts to get the percent
dfg['percent'] = dfg['Size'].div(dfm.Tested.value_counts()).mul(100).round(1)

# reshape to plot
dfp = dfg.reset_index().pivot(index='Proficiency', columns='Tested', values='percent')

# display(dfp)
Tested             BOY   EOY
Proficiency                 
Remedial          34.8   9.9
Below Proficient  28.7  12.7
Proficient        27.1  25.4
Advanced           8.8  51.9
```

### Plot

```py
ax = dfp.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 5), rot=0, color=['orchid', 'teal'])

# formatting
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(mtick.PercentFormatter())
ax.set_ylabel('Students at Proficiency Level', fontsize=18)
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax.set_title('Bushwick Middle Change in Proficiency Levels', fontsize=25)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=25)
ax.legend(fontsize=25)
_ = plt.yticks(fontsize=15)

# add bar labels
for p in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(p, fmt='%.1f%%', label_type='edge', fontsize=12)
    
# pad the spacing between the number and the edge of the figure
ax.margins(y=0.2)
```

- See the bar labels match `dfp`

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect. Much easier to manipulate the data before graphing. I am newer to Python and still learning.